# Visual Studio Localization Settings when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there any way to change the localization settings of Visual Studio when in debug mode.

For example when hovering over a date the format of the intellisense that pops up is `"MM/dd/yyyy"` were I would like to to be in the format `"dd/MM/yyyy"`.

I tried setting the Localization setting under tools > options > International Settings to same as windows but this didn't seem to work.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the operating system language.  Control Panel + Region and Language applet.  Rather a good idea since that ensures that you are debugging code the way your customer will be running it.  Overriding the culture on your UI thread to be different from the system language is a very fertile source of hard to diagnose bugs.

Comment: Cheers thanks very much will try this and get back to you if successful or not.